# add,edit,search,page button in below JQgrid MVC4

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, jqgrid, mvcjqgrid

I use the Following way of method to bind the data in JQGrid.It working Fine.

My question is,The buttons like add,edit,page,search... in bottom of the grid(which is highlighted in the ReferImage) does not show.

How to insert add,edit,search,page button in below JQgrid??

Add Script Files Like the following Order,

```
    <link href="~/Content/Content/redmond/jquery-ui-1.10.4.custom.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="~/JQGrid/css/ui.jqgrid.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="~/JQGrid/js/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/JQGrid/js/i18n/grid.locale-en.js"></script>
    <script src="~/JQGrid/js/jquery.jqGrid.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/JQGrid/js/jquery.jqGrid.src.js"></script>
```

JqGrid Script

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () { 
    $(function () {
        jQuery("#persontable").jqGrid({
            url: '/Home/passjson',
            datatype: "json",
            mtype: 'GET',
            colNames: ['FirstName', 'LastName', 'LevelOfEducation','Company'],
            colModel: [
                        { name: 'FirstName', index: 'FirstName', width: 100, align: 'left' },
                        { name: 'LastName', index: 'LastName', width: 110, align: 'left' },
                        { name: 'LevelOfEducation', index: 'LevelOfEducation', width: 110, align: 'left' },
                        { name: 'Company', index: 'Company', width: 110, align: 'left' }
            ],
            rowNum: 10,
            rowList: [10, 20, 30],
            sort: 'FirstName',
            viewrecords: true,
            gridview: true,
            loadonce: true,
            toolbar: [true, 'bottom'],
            multiselect: true,
            pager: "#jQGridPager",
            cellEdit: false,
            rowNumbers: true,
            viewrecords: true
        });

        $('#persontable').jqGrid('navGrid', '#jQGridPager',
        {
            edit: true,
            add: true,
            del: true,
            search: true,
            searchtext: "Search",
            addtext: "Add",
            edittext: "Edit",
            deltext: "Delete",
            refreshtext: "Refresh",
            position: 'left'
        });

    });
    });
</script>   
<table id="persontable" ></table>
```

Refer Image
[image]

Comment: Do you have the pager named `jQGridPager`?

Comment: @nazmoonnoor yes.But it was not working

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all you should use *either* `jquery.jqGrid.min.js` *or* `jquery.jqGrid.src.js` but not both together.

You problem seems me very easy. You use the option `pager: "#jQGridPager"` of jqGrid and you call `navGrid` with parameter `'#jQGridPager'`, but **you don't defined** empty `<div>` with `id="jQGridPager"`. So I suppose that you should just append

```html
<table id="persontable"></table>
```

with

```html
<div id="jQGridPager"></div>
```

By the way the option `sort: 'FirstName'` is not exist. Probably you mean `sortname: 'FirstName'`.

Answer (score 0):

The button images that jqgrid uses come from the jquery theme. Check if the images are in subdirectory name `images` of theme css, in your case probably in redmond/images folder.

Comment: Even Page also didnt displayed